# Scale a Gtkmm::Entry

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am trying to scale in both dimensions a Gtkmm Entry object. I wasn't able to find anything useful for this. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer. There is the set_size_request property that can change the size of the entry.

```
entryBox[i * ROW_SZ + j]->set_size_request(40);
```